# delete and set a pointer in the same instruction

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do :

```
A* a1 = /*something*/;
A* a2 = /*something else*/;
A* tmp = a1;
a1 = a2; // both a1 and a2 points to "something else"
delete tmp; // "something" is deleted
```

In a single statement where setting is done first? Something like that :

```
A* a1 = /*something*/;
A* a2 = /*something else*/;
set_and_delete(a1, a2); // ok
```

It's important to me that setting come fist, and not do :

```
delete a1;
a1 = a2;
```

(if needed, I can explain why, but it seems that the previous example is enough to understand the question)

Comment: This is what smart pointers are for (amongst other things).

Comment: However, it's really not clear why the ordering is important here.

Comment: Example: a list. You will do

a1 = a1.nexta1, so if a1 is deleted before reseted, it will go wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart pointers like [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) have a member function for this exact situation:

```
a1.reset(a2); // assuming a2 is a raw pointer

a1 = std::move(a2); // If a2 is also a unique_ptr.
```

For usual raw pointers you will have to write an appropriate function template:

```
template <typename T> struct identity {using type=T;};

template <typename T>
void set_and_delete(T*& ptr, typename identity<T>::type* new_val)
{
    auto tmp = ptr;
    ptr = new_val;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Note how we have to make the second parameter a non-deduced context to ensure no deduction conflicts occur. cv-qualifiers still work properly though.

Comment: Assuming `a2` is also a smart pointer, then you could just do `a1 = a2;`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You would have to `move` - but yes.

Comment: Can you explain why someone would use `typename identity<T>::type*` instead of `T*` (why there would be a deduction failure) ?

Comment: `int const* p = new int; set_and_delete(p, new int);`
You could use two template parameters, too.

Answer (score 0):

You said "in the same instruction" which makes me think you're trying to do something here with threads. Like an atomic delete and set to nullptr operation.

If that's so, the trick is not to delete and set at the exact same time. The trick is the atomic pointer update. I believe the `std::atomic` C++ library can help you. You want `compare_exchange_strong()`

Create a tmp variable set to 0. Copy the value of the pointer you want to delete into another variable called pointer_expected. Check that for 0. Now exchange the values of pointer and tmp with the expected value set to pointer_expected.

I believe that will result in you setting the pointer to zero and getting the pointer's previous value in tmp which will then be safe to delete. If another thread has already done this, you'll get a zero value, which won't match your expected value and you'll know not to delete it.